# How to put a conditional output in Matlab function?

Tags: function, matlab, conditional-statements

If my function is:

```
[k_well_testing_dd_sisim,k_well_testing_bup_sisim]=k_from_well_testing_general(nModel_want,P_dd,t_dd_days,P_bup,t_bup_days)
```

Now I have this condition in my function's body:

```
if nargin==5

k_well_testing_bup_sisim=by_some_formulas; % I get k_well_testing_bup_sisim by some formulas

end
```

Notice that I will get `k_well_testing_bup_sisim` as the output only when `nargin==5` is satisfied i.e. I have 5 input arguments to my function. However, if I choose not to input 5 arguments, how can I make sure that outputs in first line of function definition ignores the second output variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

varagout = myfun(...);

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/varargout.html